# How to limit inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a base class that provides 2 methods `DeleteAccount` and `AccountDetail`. I wanna create 2 derived classes to assign to the methods. `Administrator` can assign both while `Moderator` can assign just one.

```
public abstract class AccountManager
{
    public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {

    }

    public void AccountDetail(string userId)
    {

    }
}

public class Administrator : AccountManager
{

}

public class Moderator : AccountManager
{

}
```

Usage:

```
var admin = new Administrator();
var mod = new Moderator();

admin.DeleteAccount("foo"); // allowed
admin.AccountDetail("foo"); // allowed

mod.DeleteAccount("foo"); // NOT allowed
mod.AccountDetail("foo"); // allowed
```

How to prevent the derived class `Moderator` to assign to `DeleteAccount` method?

Thank you!

Comment: Move `DeleteAccount` to the `Administrator` object?

Comment: Why having DeleteAccount method in generic class when its needed only in specific objects, that's  the base of inheritance.

Comment: @Ipsit But maybe DeleteAccount is needed by other sub-classes?

Comment: @kame Then create another abstract object that inherits from the base that adds the delete method

Comment: @kame The idea should be to introduce DeleteAccount method in a class which can DeleteAccount like in Administrator, further we can have DepartmentAdministrator, OfficeAdministrator as child classes of Administrator which will  also be able to Delete accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language doesn't support this, and no proper OOP language should.
Such a 'feature' would violate the substitution principle.

The basic idea:

```
public abstract class AccountManager
{
    //public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    protected void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {

    }

    ...
}

public class Administrator : AccountManager
{
   public void DeleteAccount(string userId) { base.DeleteAccount(userId); }
}

public class Moderator : AccountManager
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned in your current scenario it looks like the delete account should just be a method of the administrator class. The other option is depending on the rest of your model, remove the inheritance and just have a flag IsAdmin on a non-abstract AccountManagerClass. In the DeleteAccount method, you can then check this flag

```
public class AccountManager
{
    public bool IsAdmin {get; private set;}

    public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {
        if (isAdmin)
        {
            //do delete
        }
        else
        {
            //tell them they can't
        }
    }
.... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is should be a role-based authentication
Inheritance in OOP does not purpose for Authorization. Anyway, you can code in any way you like

```
public abstract class AccountManager
{
    public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {
    }

    public void AccountDetail(string userId)
    {

    }
}

public class Administrator : AccountManager
{

}

public class Moderator : AccountManager
{
    public void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {
        throw new Exception("You have not a right permission");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's have said, this is an odd way to handle permissions. But, it's your baby, so if you want to do it this way it's OK - propably there are other reasons.

For completeness - some of the examples here are missing the correct use of virtual/override, which is as follows:

```
public abstract class AccountManager
{
    public virtual void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {

    }

    public virtual void AccountDetail(string userId)
    {

    }
}

public class Administrator : AccountManager
{

}

public class Moderator : AccountManager
{
    public override void DeleteAccount(string userId)
    {
        throw new Exception("You have not a right permission");
    }

}
```